# jQuery: 'class=ui.dragable' Not Being Applied to Whole Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I am currently trying to develop a prototype using jQuery that makes a whole stack of cards draggable within the window once dealt. I am noticing that the entire stack is not getting the `class=ui.draggable` property within my console on my website. I am not sure as to why only some of these cards within the array would be getting the property seemingly at random each time. Would appreciate any feedback on this!

```
$('#deal').click(function () {
    dealCard(randomCard());
});

$( function init() {
    $(".drop").droppable( { drop: dropCard } );
} ); 

function dropCard(event, ui) {
    $('#drop').html( 'The card "' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped.' ); 
}

var cardsInDeck = new Array();
var numberOfCardsInDeck = 51;
cardsInDeck[0] = "ClubAce";
cardsInDeck[1] = "Clubs2";
cardsInDeck[2] = "Clubs3";
cardsInDeck[3] = "Clubs4";
cardsInDeck[4] = "Clubs5";
cardsInDeck[5] = "Clubs6";
cardsInDeck[6] = "Clubs7";
cardsInDeck[7] = "Clubs8";
cardsInDeck[8] = "Clubs9";
cardsInDeck[9] = "Clubs10";
cardsInDeck[10] = "ClubsJack";
cardsInDeck[11] = "ClubsKing";
cardsInDeck[12] = "ClubsQueen";
cardsInDeck[13] = "DiamondsAce";
cardsInDeck[14] = "Diamonds2";
cardsInDeck[15] = "Diamonds3";
cardsInDeck[16] = "Diamonds4";
cardsInDeck[17] = "Diamonds5";
cardsInDeck[18] = "Diamonds6";
cardsInDeck[19] = "Diamonds7";
cardsInDeck[20] = "Diamonds8";
cardsInDeck[21] = "Diamonds9";
cardsInDeck[22] = "Diamonds10";
cardsInDeck[23] = "DiamondsQueen";
cardsInDeck[24] = "DiamondsJack";
cardsInDeck[25] = "DiamondsKing";
cardsInDeck[26] = "HeartsAce";
cardsInDeck[27] = "Hearts2";
cardsInDeck[28] = "Hearts3";
cardsInDeck[29] = "Hearts4";
cardsInDeck[30] = "Hearts5";
cardsInDeck[31] = "Hearts6";
cardsInDeck[32] = "Hearts7";
cardsInDeck[33] = "Hearts8";
cardsInDeck[34] = "Hearts9";
cardsInDeck[35] = "Hearts10";
cardsInDeck[36] = "HeartsJack";
cardsInDeck[37] = "HeartsKing";
cardsInDeck[38] = "HeartsQueen";
cardsInDeck[39] = "SpadesAce";
cardsInDeck[40] = "Spades2";
cardsInDeck[41] = "Spades3";
cardsInDeck[42] = "Spades4";
cardsInDeck[43] = "Spades5";
cardsInDeck[44] = "Spades6";
cardsInDeck[45] = "Spades7";
cardsInDeck[46] = "Spades8";
cardsInDeck[47] = "Spades9";
cardsInDeck[48] = "Spades10";
cardsInDeck[49] = "SpadesJack";
cardsInDeck[50] = "SpadesQueen";
cardsInDeck[51] = "SpadesKing";

function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck === 0) return false;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("id", cardsInDeck[i]);
    img.setAttribute("height", "100px");
    img.src ="../Cards/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    console.log(cardsInDeck[i]);
    removeCard(i);
    $("#" + cardsInDeck[i]).draggable({ containment: 'document' });
}

function randomCard() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfCardsInDeck);  
}

function removeCard(c)
{
    for (j=c; j <= numberOfCardsInDeck - 2; j++)
    {
        cardsInDeck[j] = cardsInDeck[j+1];
    }
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can also use `$(img).draggable()` instead of `$("#" + cardsInDeck[i]).draggable()`. When you remove the card the order of the array is changed, so your index is no longer correct. So you likely get another card name.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this part of your snippet:

```js
function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck === 0) return false;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("id", cardsInDeck[i]);
    img.setAttribute("height", "100px");
    img.src ="../Cards/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    removeCard(i);
    $("#" + cardsInDeck[i]).draggable({ containment: 'document' });
}
```

Within `dealCard()`, when you call `removeCard(i)` (second last line), it changes the content of `cardsInDeck`. Because of this change, when you use `cardsInDeck` in the next (last) line you don't always get the correct id.

Possible fixes: store the `id` (`cardsInDeck[i]`) before calling `removeCard(i)` and use it later. Alternatively, you can just swap the two bottom lines making `removeCard(i)` the last.

Demo:

```js
$('#deal').click(function () {
    dealCard(randomCard());
});

$( function init() {
    $(".drop").droppable( { drop: dropCard } );
} ); 

function dropCard(event, ui) {
    $('#drop').html( 'The card "' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped.' ); 
}

var cardsInDeck = new Array();
var numberOfCardsInDeck = 51;
cardsInDeck[0] = "ClubAce";
cardsInDeck[1] = "Clubs2";
cardsInDeck[2] = "Clubs3";
cardsInDeck[3] = "Clubs4";
cardsInDeck[4] = "Clubs5";
cardsInDeck[5] = "Clubs6";
cardsInDeck[6] = "Clubs7";
cardsInDeck[7] = "Clubs8";
cardsInDeck[8] = "Clubs9";
cardsInDeck[9] = "Clubs10";
cardsInDeck[10] = "ClubsJack";
cardsInDeck[11] = "ClubsKing";
cardsInDeck[12] = "ClubsQueen";
cardsInDeck[13] = "DiamondsAce";
cardsInDeck[14] = "Diamonds2";
cardsInDeck[15] = "Diamonds3";
cardsInDeck[16] = "Diamonds4";
cardsInDeck[17] = "Diamonds5";
cardsInDeck[18] = "Diamonds6";
cardsInDeck[19] = "Diamonds7";
cardsInDeck[20] = "Diamonds8";
cardsInDeck[21] = "Diamonds9";
cardsInDeck[22] = "Diamonds10";
cardsInDeck[23] = "DiamondsQueen";
cardsInDeck[24] = "DiamondsJack";
cardsInDeck[25] = "DiamondsKing";
cardsInDeck[26] = "HeartsAce";
cardsInDeck[27] = "Hearts2";
cardsInDeck[28] = "Hearts3";
cardsInDeck[29] = "Hearts4";
cardsInDeck[30] = "Hearts5";
cardsInDeck[31] = "Hearts6";
cardsInDeck[32] = "Hearts7";
cardsInDeck[33] = "Hearts8";
cardsInDeck[34] = "Hearts9";
cardsInDeck[35] = "Hearts10";
cardsInDeck[36] = "HeartsJack";
cardsInDeck[37] = "HeartsKing";
cardsInDeck[38] = "HeartsQueen";
cardsInDeck[39] = "SpadesAce";
cardsInDeck[40] = "Spades2";
cardsInDeck[41] = "Spades3";
cardsInDeck[42] = "Spades4";
cardsInDeck[43] = "Spades5";
cardsInDeck[44] = "Spades6";
cardsInDeck[45] = "Spades7";
cardsInDeck[46] = "Spades8";
cardsInDeck[47] = "Spades9";
cardsInDeck[48] = "Spades10";
cardsInDeck[49] = "SpadesJack";
cardsInDeck[50] = "SpadesQueen";
cardsInDeck[51] = "SpadesKing";

function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck === 0) return false;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("id", cardsInDeck[i]);
    img.setAttribute("height", "100px");
    img.src ="../Cards/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".png";
    img.title=cardsInDeck[i];
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    $("#" + cardsInDeck[i]).draggable({ containment: 'document' }); // <------- changed the order here
    removeCard(i);                                                  // <------- changed the order here
}

function randomCard() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfCardsInDeck);  
}

function removeCard(c)
{
    for (j=c; j <= numberOfCardsInDeck - 2; j++)
    {
        cardsInDeck[j] = cardsInDeck[j+1];
    }
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css">
      
<button id="deal">DEAL</button>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {

  var cards = [{
      label: "♣A",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Ace"
    },
    {
      label: "♣2",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Two"
    },
    {
      label: "♣3",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Three"
    },
    {
      label: "♣4",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Four"
    },
    {
      label: "♣5",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Five"
    },
    {
      label: "♣6",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Six"
    },
    {
      label: "♣7",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Seven"
    },
    {
      label: "♣8",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Eight"
    },
    {
      label: "♣9",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Nine"
    },
    {
      label: "♣10",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Ten"
    },
    {
      label: "♣J",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Jack"
    },
    {
      label: "♣Q",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "Queen"
    },
    {
      label: "♣K",
      suit: "Clubs",
      name: "King"
    },
    {
      label: "♦A",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Ace"
    },
    {
      label: "♦2",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Two"
    },
    {
      label: "♦3",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Three"
    },
    {
      label: "♦4",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Four"
    },
    {
      label: "♦5",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Five"
    },
    {
      label: "♦6",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Six"
    },
    {
      label: "♦7",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Seven"
    },
    {
      label: "♦8",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Eight"
    },
    {
      label: "♦9",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Nine"
    },
    {
      label: "♦10",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Ten"
    },
    {
      label: "♦J",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Jack"
    },
    {
      label: "♦Q",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "Queen"
    },
    {
      label: "♦K",
      suit: "Diamonds",
      name: "King"
    },
    {
      label: "♥A",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Ace"
    },
    {
      label: "♥2",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Two"
    },
    {
      label: "♥3",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Three"
    },
    {
      label: "♥4",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Four"
    },
    {
      label: "♥5",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Five"
    },
    {
      label: "♥6",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Six"
    },
    {
      label: "♥7",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Seven"
    },
    {
      label: "♥8",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Eight"
    },
    {
      label: "♥9",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Nine"
    },
    {
      label: "♥10",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Ten"
    },
    {
      label: "♥J",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Jack"
    },
    {
      label: "♥Q",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "Queen"
    },
    {
      label: "♥K",
      suit: "Hearts",
      name: "King"
    },
    {
      label: "♠A",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Ace"
    },
    {
      label: "♠2",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Two"
    },
    {
      label: "♠3",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Three"
    },
    {
      label: "♠4",
      ssuit: "Spades",
      name: "Four"
    },
    {
      label: "♠5",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Five"
    },
    {
      label: "♠6",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Six"
    },
    {
      label: "♠7",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Seven"
    },
    {
      label: "♠8",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Eight"
    },
    {
      label: "♠9",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Nine"
    },
    {
      label: "♠10",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Ten"
    },
    {
      label: "♠J",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Jack"
    },
    {
      label: "♠Q",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "Queen"
    },
    {
      label: "♠K",
      suit: "Spades",
      name: "King"
    }
  ];

  function makeDeck(shuffle) {
    if (shuffle == undefined) {
      shuffle = false;
    }
    var deck = [];

    if (shuffle) {
      console.log("Shuffling");
      var myCards = cards.map((x) => x);
      var card;
      for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        var ind = Math.floor(myCards.length * Math.random());
        card = myCards[ind];
        deck.push(card);
        myCards.splice(ind, 1);
      }
    } else {
      deck.push(myCards);
    }
    return deck;
  }

  function dropCard(event, ui) {
    $(this).html(ui.draggable.attr('title') + ' was dropped.');
  }

  var cardsInDeck = makeDeck(true);

  function dealCard() {
    if (cardsInDeck.length === 0) return false;
    var card = cardsInDeck.pop();
    var img = $("<img>", {
      id: card.suit + card.name,
      class: "card",
      src: "https://dummyimage.com/150 x 200/eeeeee/000000.png&text=" + card.label,
      title: card.name + " of " + card.suit
    }).css({
      "border-radius": "6px",
      height: "100px"
    }).appendTo(".cards").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      containment: 'document'
    });
    console.log("Card Dealt", card.label);
  }

  function init() {
    $(".drop").droppable({
      accept: ".card",
      drop: dropCard
    });
  }

  init();

  $('#deal').click(function() {
    dealCard();
  });
});
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css">

<button id="deal">DEAL</button>
<hr>
<div class="cards"></div>
<div class="drop"></div>
```

This is an example that is a bit more complex, yet the same basic apply.

```
  function dealCard() {
    if (cardsInDeck.length === 0) return false;
    var card = cardsInDeck.pop();
    var img = $("<img>", {
      id: card.suit + card.name,
      class: "card",
      src: "https://dummyimage.com/150 x 200/eeeeee/000000.png&text=" + card.label,
      title: card.name + " of " + card.suit
    }).css({
      "border-radius": "6px",
      height: "100px"
    }).appendTo(".cards").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      containment: 'document'
    });
    console.log("Card Dealt", card.label);
  }
```

This pulls a Card object from the top of the deck (using `.pop()`). A new `<img>` element is created with specific attributes. It is appended to the document and made draggable.

The User can now drag it. Droppable must be configured correctly too.